Is this a valid sitemap formal (XSL) for Google Search Console?
I'm using Joomla's JLSitemap extenion with XSL enabled in settings. This is what's generated: https://lenkraddesign.eu/sitemap.xml
I tried submitting that to Google 3 times now. Last time on 2nd June, so I believe enough time passed for it to not be some "file unknown yet" waiting type of error. GSC itself only reports useless, user-unfriendly "Couldn't fetch" + "Couldn't read sitemap" messages.
I asked on Google forums, in 2 different languages, there was no consensus or anything that helped me either.
Both Bing and Yandex accepted the sitemap with no issue, all SEO tools I tried reported it as valid sitemap as well. Only small company called Google has unidentifiable issues.
URL check in GSC:

Is this format valid? If not, why?

Looks fine to me. Would you try the following:


Use the URL Inspection Tool in GSC to see if Google can access and fetch your sitemap. This can give you more specific error messages if there are any access issues.


While unlikely, XSL processing might be causing some unexpected behavior. Try temporarily disabling XSL in JLSitemap settings and see if Google can fetch the sitemap then.



@Maniac it does and says it's indexed, even. A shame that Google can't show clear errors, as I don't even know what to potentially report as a "bug" in the extension.

Did you try to temporarily disable XSL and add the XML sitemap again?

I'd like to keep it enabled, but yes, that also didn't work
